# Chew-resistant yet lightweight dog leash

Tags: dogs, leashes

My dog likes to grab her leash in her mouth and pull on it or just hold it.  She doesn't really go at it like with a chew toy, but over time it abades and eventually gets weak enough to break.

Annie weighs between 25 and 30 pounds.  I don't want to get a metal chain because they are heavier.  Is there a leash design for sale that's light for a small/medium dog, but is more abrasion and saliva resistant than the common webbing that I find at the stores now?

## Update

The leash did not break where it had been worn through chewing.
Rather, it failed where the last inch of webbing was folded over to loop through the metal ring of the hook.  It appears to have simply been sewn, and this fell apart.  This is not someplace the dog can reach to mouth.  Rather, it's just poor quality work and/or exposure to sun and moisture (I notice the webbing is kind of stiff and dry compared to a new leash).

So, I'm looking for something lightweight and good quality.  Not showing much effect from being held in a dog's mouth is still desirable, but is more cosmetic than critical.

Comment: shopping questions are off topic on our site.

Comment: you could think about a combination of leash and chain. Chain near the dogs head or where it prefer to bite and leash all other way to your hand. So you would have lighter weight than chain only, but durable where the dog holds/bites/chews it.

Comment: Since we are an international community, we cannot provide shopping advice. Anything we recommend may not be available or may have different properties in different locations. Even several items by the same manufacturer in the same location may have different properties due to age or storage conditions.